# How can I access to UI components from an external function?

Tags: c++, qt, function, user-interface, qt-creator

From the class mainWindows "Principal". I can run this Code perfectly:

```
ui->label1->setText("texto");
```

From another external function I need to run the same code.

Answer (score 0):

If it external function placed in other class.
You can assign link to your ***ui***.

```
Ui::MainWindowUI *MainUi=0;
...
void Configurations::setMainUI(Ui::MainWindowUI* u){
    if (u){
        MainUi=u;
    }
}
```

mainWindows:

```
instanceConfigurations.setMainUI(ui);
```

And then can get access to ***ui*** via:

```
void Configurations::setLabel(){
       MainUi->label1->setText("texto");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Although you didn't specify, it looks like you're using C++, so I'll assume that's correct.)

The `ui` variable is most likely a private member of the main window class, so you can use various standard approaches to make it accessible from outside of that class.  If you're not worried about breaking encapsulation, one of the simplest ways is to add a method to your class that returns the `ui` member.  I can't recall the exact types involved so this will be slightly incomplete, but it should look something like this (where `MainWindow` is your class):

```
MainWindow::UI* MainWindow::getUi()
{
    return ui;
}
```

where `<main window class>` is the actual name of your class.

After that, any code that has a pointer to your main window instance (I'll call it `mainWindow` here) can do something like...

```
mainWindow->getUi()->label1->setText("texto");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `MainWindow` needs to expose the text in its API. You should never expose implementation details like the `ui` instance directly:

   ```
   class MainWindow ... {
     Q_OBJECT
     Q_PROPERTY (QString someText READ someText WRITE setSomeText)
     ...
   public:
     QString someText() const { return ui.label1->text(); }
     void setSomeText(const QString & text) { ui.label1->setText(text); }
     ...
   };
   ```
2. The external function needs to be passed the instance of the window:

   ```
   void function(MainWindow * w) {
     w->setSomeText("Hello");
   }

   int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
     ...
     MainWindow window;
     window.show();
     ...
     function(&window);
     ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `connect()` in your 'external class'. That means: declare the connect on the  constructor of the classor on the beggining of your 'xternal function' and then emit the signal, attaching it to a slot in you rmain window.

Then  you just need to declare a slot in your mainwindow with `ui->label1->setText("texto");`inside